# Wordpress returns white page when searching

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Whenever I search on my site I get an blank error page. I have tried the following:

1. Disable plugin.
2. Turn on debug.
3. Scanned my code with theme checker for deprecated tags.

Search.php

get_header(); ?>

```
    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'shape' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

            <?php shape_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php shape_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'search' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
    </section><!-- #primary .content-area -->
```

Searchform.php

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" role="search">
    <label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'shape' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" class="field" name="s" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search &hellip;', 'shape' ); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'shape' ); ?>" />
</form>
```

The weird thing is that all my html show up when searching, but I am still getting a white page of death.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please share your code in the question... not just links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All code is readable with CTRL+U. So your WordPress works. One of the problems is the display:none value in the CSS under .search class. So delete the .search { display:none; } line from CSS.